# Excel Vba Copy Method of Worksheet fails - Copy from xlApp to ThisWorkbook

Tags: excel, vba

I posted a question recently on interacting with another WB in a separate instance of Excel.

[How to add Open Workbook to "Application.Workbooks" collection and/or interact with Workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63058197/how-to-add-open-workbook-to-application-workbooks-collection-and-or-interact-w)

But I had hardcoded the copy/paste range for testing, and now I'm having trouble with coping the entire worksheet to the "main wb". Eg: `xlApp.Worksheets(1).Copy After:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)`

I get the error `Copy Method of Worksheet Failed` and ideas how to adjust this to work?

```
Public Sub Copy_External_WB()
 Dim xlApp As Excel.Application, xlBook As Worksheet, i As Long

 For i = 1 To 10
   On Error Resume Next
   Set xlApp = GetObject("Book" & i).Application
   If Err.Number = -2147221020 Then
        Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
   Else
        On Error GoTo 0
        Exit For
   End If
 Next i

 If Not xlApp Is Nothing Then
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Worksheets(1)
    Debug.Print xlApp.hWnd, Application.hWnd
 Else
    MsgBox "No Excel session with Book(1 - 10) open could be found..."
    xlApp.Quit: Exit Sub
 End If
 
 'Dim CopyFrom As Range
 'Set CopyFrom = xlBook.Range("A1:AQ56")

 'Dim DS As Worksheet
 'Set DS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Merged")
 'DS.Range("A1:AQ56").Resize(CopyFrom.Rows.Count).Value = CopyFrom.Value
 
 xlApp.Worksheets(1).Copy After:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
 
 xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
 
   xlApp.Quit
 xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True
 Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think you can copy a worksheet like that between instances. You can save it to file and then open it in the instance where your code is running.

Comment: Just seems odd, I can copy a `Range` but not a `Worksheet`?

Comment: @BigBen - I can't copy a worksheet between two different instances

Comment: How are you starting the second instance of excel?

Comment: If I hold down Ctrl and drag the sheet tab I can't drop it into the second instance, and using the "Move or Copy..." menu the second instance is not listed

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers - I wonder if you can use the clipboard here... copy all cells instead of copying the sheet.

Comment: For a separate instance, hold down Alt while right-clicking the Excel taskbar icon and selecting "Excel" - you'll get a prompt asking you if you want to start a separate instance of Excel

Comment: @BigBen I think if it came down to that, I'd fine it easier to save/open/copy/close/delete WB, partly because I have that code handy and it will guarantee correct coping of the worksheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot copy a whole sheet object between different Excel instances.

Options:

- Use VBA to save the other workbook to file, then open it in the instance where your code is running, and copy the sheet to your workbook
- Copy (eg) the `UsedRange` from the other instance's worksheet, then paste in your primary instance workbook